# How do you output a datetime variable from a for loop without altering the format?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop

I have a file with lines containing date and time throughout it, e.g.:

```
PPS: 0,1096134, Sun Sep  6 16:05:32 2020,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I've used a for loop to find the lines and extract the date and time values. I'm trying to store the values into a variable 'date':

```
idx = ['PPS']
date = []
from datetime import datetime

with open('output2.csv','r') as input:  
    
    for line in input:
        if  any(idx in line for idx in idx):
            
            dt = line[16:-13]
            dt = datetime.strptime(dt, "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
            print(dt)
            date.append(dt)

print(date)
```

Printing 'dt' in the loop outputs the format I'm looking for:

```
2020-09-06 16:05:32
```

But appending 'dt' to 'date' removes the formatting and outputs the following when printed outside the loop:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 6, 16, 5, 32)
```

Why does this happen and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `print(x)` formats it with `__str__`, but if you print a list, the items in that list will use `__repr__`, why do you care, though?

Comment: Thanks, I thought date was wrong because I didn't realise print(x) was different to printing a list. Knowing about _repr_ is useful though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = 'Sun Sep 6 16:05:32 2020'
dt = datetime.strptime(dt, "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
dates= [dt]
```

The `__str__` of a single `datetime` object has the nice formatting:

```
print(dt)
```

Gives:

```
2020-09-06 16:05:32
```

But if you put these `datetime` objects in a list, then that is lost. The `__str__` for the list doesn't call `__str__` of the datetime objects inside

```
print(dates)
```

Gives:

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 6, 16, 5, 32)]
```

However the objects are still the same. So you can do `print(dates[0])` to get the nice formatting.

Or you may use a loop:

```
for dt_entry in dates:
    print(dt_entry)
```

if you must

Answer (score 0):

When printing a list the `__repr__` verison of the entailed class instances are used. When printing the class instance itself you print the `__str__` version of it.

You can use

```
print(*date) # decompose the list into its elements, print each with str
```

to print the elemnts of the list itself (using **str** that way).